# The method add(String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Tags: java, string, arraylist, jlist

I am running the following code:

```
    public ArrayList<String> equipAvail;
        {
        equButton2 = new JButton();
        equButton2.setText("Apply");
        equButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                //read the contents of equlist2 
                for(int i=0;i<equList2.getModel().getSize();i++){
                    //fill equipAvail ArrayList with the contents of equlist2 
                    //System.out.println(equList2.getModel().getElementAt(i));
                    //System.out.println(equList2.getModel().getElementAt(i) instanceof String);
                    equipAvail.add(equList2.getModel().getElementAt(i));
                    //pass equipAvail to the user's EquipmentAvailable property
                    user.setEquipmentAvailable(equipAvail);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

If I comment out the line `equipAvail.add(equList2.getModel().getElementAt(i));`, and run the currently commented out line `//System.out.println(equList2.getModel().getElementAt(i));`, it does print the selections to the console.
If I run the line `//System.out.println(equList2.getModel().getElementAt(i) instanceof String);`, it reports true for as many objects as are populated into `equList2`.

Yet somehow, when I try to run it as shown, it won't even compile. Gives the error "The method add(String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (Object)". If I use `.toString()` at the end of the equipAvail line, it will compile but then give me the same error when I click the button in my GUI.

I need `equipAvail` to be an ArrayList and to be populated with all of the strings that appear in `equList2`.

Why can't I add these objects that I know are strings into an ArrayList using equilAvail.add?

How can I populate equipAvail with the entries from equList2?

Thank you!!

For context, it may be helpful to note that `equList2` begins its life like this:

```
    private JList getEquList2() {
    if(equList2 == null) {
        ListModel equList2Model = 
            new DefaultComboBoxModel(
                    new String[] {""});
        equList2 = new JList();
        equList2.setModel(equList2Model);
        equList2.setVisibleRowCount(4);
    }
    return equList2;
}
```

But then is updated to contain some additional data using a `equList2.setListData(equList1.getSelectedValues());` command tied to a 'Move' button that moves a subset of equList1 entries to equList2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListModel is a generic type, but you are using it as a raw type.

Perhaps`ListModel<String> = new DefaultComboxBoxModel<String>(new String[] {""})`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I made this change and also changed each `JList` into `JList<String>`. Unfortunately updating this did not resolve the issue - I am getting the same error. Is there some way I need to modify the line `equList2.setModel(equList2Model);` as well?

Comment: @jaydex I forgot about `equList2` itself. It should be declared a `JList<String>` and the return type of the method `getEquList2` should also be JList<String>.

Comment: @jaydex In general, you should not use raw types. When you look at the javadoc and you see a type that is `Something<E>` that is a clue that this is a generic and you need to fill something in for the `E`. So everywhere you use a generic in your code, specify the type.

Comment: I made sure that all of the JList instances are no longer used as generic (all as JList<String>). There are no more warnings in the IDE about raw types etc. However, the issue persists that `equList2.getModel().getElementAt(i)`, a string, will not pass into the 'ArrayList<String> equipAvail` using `equipAvail.add(equList2.getModel().getElementAt(i))`. I get a NPE at the line. Any other advice??

Comment: I figured it out! I needed to add `equipAvail = new ArrayList<String>();` before the for loop to initialize it. Thank you very much for your assistance!!